# AngularJS ng-repeat data is not binding multiple listbox in Internet Explorer

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer, listbox

**Problem:**
     Here i tried to getting selected values in listbox(multiple) for edit screen, it is running good but only in '**Internet Explorer Browser**' values are not binding it showing {{data.Text_Field}}. below i given this code.

**code:**

```
<select class="form-control"  name="field10"  id="field10" multiple ng-model="editfield.Additional_Info10"  required="content.Is_Mandatory" ng-blur="editfield.Additional_Info10=dataListSelect(editfield.Additional_Info10)" ng-init="defaultEditDropDownData(content.Value_Default_Bind_Object_Type_ID)" >
    <option value=""  disabled selected>--Select--</option>
    <option ng-repeat="data in tree_data" title="{{data.Value_Field}}" ng-selected="data.Value_Field==editcheckboxData(editfield.Additional_Info10,data.Value_Field,2)"   value="{{data.Value_Field}}">{{data.Text_Field}}</option>
</select>
```

**Am getting output like that:**

[image]

Comment: Can you please post a code snippet that reproduces this problem ?

Comment: Which version of explorer and angular are you using?